# how can I automatically get the same methods in multiple classes with different inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a singleton class that I want accessible via a helper method on multiple classes...

One of my classes inherits from CCLayer:

```
@interface Game : CCLayer
```

the other NSObject:

```
@interface Question : NSObject
```

...  So my thought was to create a class:

```
#import "Storeizer.h"

@implementation Storeizer

-(StorageMechanism*)store {
    return [StorageMechanism sharedStorageMechanism];
}

@end
```

And have both Game and Question classes inherit from Storeizer so that they can automatically have a self.store convenience method....  However, this is a problem since my other classes already inherit from different objects (CCLayer and NSObject).  So, I am a little confused how to proceed, and am wondering if this convenience method is more trouble than it's worth.  I just come from a world where I hate to have redundant code, and having multiple classes calling [StorageMechanism sharedStorageMechanism] feels a little unfriendly on the eyes (to me at least).

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Although adding a category to NSObject may seem like an easy solution at first, later it will guarantee some difficult to track bugs, longer loading time, difficult app debugging and multiple inheritance problems (what happens if you include two categories with the same methods?). If this project will be large in the future then I would rather suggest creating protocol and sticking to the composition.

Comment: using a protocol means I will have to define this method (identically) in every class...  That kind of defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do;  I am trying to make it so that multiple classes can automatically have behavior without having to write duplicate code...

Comment: then category on NSObject seems like the only solution, its similar to multiple inheritance in some ways

Comment: you can also try to experiment with #define, you can define some text and then use the defined constant in a place of a method, it doesnt seem nice but this practice is widely used in example in GHUnit, check out this file https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/blob/master/Classes/GHTestMacros.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a category to NSObject, and import the header of the category where you are using these methods.